# How to Join Tables For My Database

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin

I have a database with two tables I am trying to Join.

```
Table1: Employee
Table2: Video_Store
```

Both of these tables have a Video store id (VS_ID). I want it to show the first and last name of the employee as well as the VS_ID they are associated with. 
When I run this statement:

```
select Video_Store.VS_ID, Video_Store.VS_Name, Employee.E_LName, Employee.E_FName
from Video_Store, Employee
```

This is the result. Each employee only has one VS_ID not six. How can reduce the redundancy?

```
1. 1    West Street Borg    James
2. 4    East Street Borg    James
3. 5    North Tremo Borg    James
4. 6    South Stree Borg    James
5. 7    Elm Street  Borg    James
6. 8    Boston Stre Borg    James
7. 1    West Street Wong    Franklin
8. 4    East Street Wong    Franklin
9. 5    North Tremo Wong    Franklin
10. 6   South Stree Wong    Franklin
11. 7   Elm Street  Wong    Franklin
12. 8   Boston Stre Wong    Franklin
13. 1   West Street Freed   Alex
14. 4   East Street Freed   Alex
15 5    North Tremo Freed   Alex
16. 6   South Stree Freed   Alex
17. 7   Elm Street  Freed   Alex
18. 8   Boston Stre Freed   Alex
19. 1   West Street James   Jared
20. 4   East Street James   Jared
21. 5   North Tremo James   Jared
22. 6   South Stree James   Jared
23. 7   Elm Street  James   Jared
24. 8   Boston Stre James   Jared
25. 1   West Street Wallace Jennifer
26. 4   East Street Wallace Jennifer
27. 5   North Tremo Wallace Jennifer
28. 6   South Stree Wallace Jennifer
29. 7   Elm Street  Wallace Jennifer
30. 8   Boston Stre Wallace Jennifer
```

Comment: You are missing the JOIN on the column `VS_ID` so you are getting a cartesian result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JOIN ... ON`

```
SELECT v.VS_ID, v.VS_Name, e.E_LName, e.E_FName
FROM Video_Store v
JOIN Employee e
ON v.VS_ID = e.VS_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Both of these tables have a Video store id (VS_ID)**. I want it to show
>   the first and last name of the employee as well as the VS_ID they are
>   associated with.

Exactly, you are simply missing to specify the `VS_ID` condition.

```
SELECTVideo_Store.VS_ID, Video_Store.VS_Name, Employee.E_LName, Employee.E_FName
FROM Video_Store 
JOIN Employee ON Video_Store.VS_ID = Employee.VS_ID
```

Since you did not specify any condition, your query was returning the cartesian product of both tables.